# python tornado async client fetch call with call back fails some times

Tags: php, python, asynchronous, tornado

When I request for pages with Tornado Async call sometimes it will grab the page content successfully but sometimes it will fail to grab the content from my local server.

It does not make sense How call back is handled.

on my local LAMP server i have this code will hold for 1 second per page.
// b.php

```
    <?php
    header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    ob_implicit_flush();
    foreach (range(1,3) as $x){
      echo $x;
      usleep(333333);
    }
    ?>
```

// c.php

```
    <?php
    header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    ob_implicit_flush();
    foreach (range(4,6) as $x){
      echo $x;
      usleep(333333);
    }
    ?>
```

// d.php

```
    <?php
    header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    ob_implicit_flush();
    foreach (range(7,9) as $x){
      echo $x;
      usleep(333333);
    }
    ?>
```

on python web Client / Server

## the code I am concerned with.

My answer why it would not work is, last call gets returned before the first one. So it would finish the callback and not be able execute other callback to write it on the screen but it should fire all the request and collect the response then should finish. any thought?
If it is possible how can I modify this code style to work instead of using yield

```
    import tornado.httpserver
    import tornado.ioloop
    import tornado.options
    import tornado.web
    import tornado.httpclient
    from tornado.options import define, options
    import tornado.gen
    
    define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)
    class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        @tornado.web.asynchronous
        @tornado.gen.engine
        def get(self):
            client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
            client.fetch("http://www.droid-life.com/?" + \
                         urllib.urlencode({"s": query}), callback=self.on_response)
            client.fetch("http://localhost/b.php", callback=self.on_response)
            client.fetch("http://localhost/c.php", callback=self.on_response)
            client.fetch("http://localhost/d.php", callback=self.on_response3)
        @tornado.web.asynchronous
        def on_response(self, response):
            body = (response.body)
            self.write(body)
        @tornado.web.asynchronous
        def on_response2(self, response):
            body = (response.body)
            self.write(body)
            client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
            client.fetch("http://localhost/d.php", callback=self.on_response3)
        def on_response3(self, response):
            body = (response.body)
            self.write(body)
            self.finish()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        tornado.options.parse_command_line()
        app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)])
        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
        http_server.listen(options.port)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This code actually works and returns results within the reasonable time around 1.1~ 1.3 seconds

```
    define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)
    class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        @tornado.web.asynchronous
        @tornado.gen.engine
        def get(self):
    
            client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
            r1,r2,r3 = yield [client.fetch("http://localhost/b.php"), \
                           client.fetch("http://localhost/c.php"), \
                           client.fetch("http://localhost/d.php") \
                            ]
            self.write(r1.body)
            self.write(r2.body)
            self.write(r3.body)
            self.finish()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        tornado.options.parse_command_line()
        app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)])
        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
        http_server.listen(options.port)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear about how exactly things are failing (and why the second version, which is both shorter and working, is not an acceptable solution), but one thing I see is that the first version of your code calls on_response3 (which calls finish) twice: once from get() and once from on_response2. Your handler will stop as soon as on_response3 is called, through whichever code path finishes first.

If you want to perform three fetches in parallel in the callback style, you must keep a counter of the number of fetches outstanding so you can call finish only after all three have finished. The callback-based equivalent of your second example would be something like this:

```
class IndexHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        self.remaining = 3
        self.responses = {}
        client.fetch("http://localhost/b.php", functools.partial(self.on_response, 'b'))
        client.fetch("http://localhost/c.php", functools.partial(self.on_response, 'c'))
        client.fetch("http://localhost/d.php", functools.partial(self.on_response, 'd'))

    def on_response(self, key, response):
        self.responses[key] = response
        self.remaining -= 1
        if self.remaining == 0:
            self.write(self.responses['b'].body)
            self.write(self.responses['c'].body)
            self.write(self.responses['d'].body)
            self.finish()
```

Comment: Correct, but how can i make sure it does not get to finish without performing all the tasks and when it is finished can call tornado.web.RequestHandler.finish() function

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, my recommendation is to use a coroutine and yield a list, exactly as you've done in your second example. If I haven't understood you, please update your original question to clarify.

Comment: Correct, what I am trying to accomplish is the my second example but i would like to accomplish the same thing with first example. I think there is got to be a way to do it but i do not know how.

Comment: I've added a callback-based example to my answer.

Comment: Oh wow... i feel like an idiot.. just adding counter before it finishes.. that works... lol

Comment: although i am not really familiar with python so figuring out that syntax for partial might have been really painful thank you very much. That is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Do you have book recommendation for python for advance / intermediate?